# Selecting all but the last element with specific class

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a style to text in all children divs except the one that has a `span` with class `.fa`

```css
.parentDiv > .column :not(.fa) {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">

  <div class="column">aaa</div>
  <div class="column">bbb</div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="fa">ccc</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I do need to keep CSS in one line as it's a part of a larger style sheet. How do I do that?

Comment: obligatory [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)  You need to override the style instead.  something like `.parentDiv > .column { font-weight: bold }` and then `.parentDiv > .column .fa { font-weight: normal }`

Comment: Any reason jQuery is included in the code example?

Comment: Sorry, bad habbit. I use jQuery all the time in other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use `:not` with `:last-of-type`

#### Snippet

```css
.parentDiv > .column:not(:last-of-type) {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">

  <div class="column">aaa</div>
  <div class="column">bbb</div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="fa">ccc</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

**EDIT** based on @Oriol's comment

> `:not(:last-of-type)` does not mean "doesn't contain a `.fa`

which makes sense, if your code could be dynamic.

here is another approach:

#### Snippet

```css
.parentDiv > .column span:not(.fa) {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="column">
    <span class="gsdfasd">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="faadsasfa">some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="fa">this will NOT BE red</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:not(:last-of-type)` does not mean "doesn't contain a `.fa`".

Comment: @Oriol given OP markup only the  last column contains `.fa` Unless OP markup is dynamic, this will do what OP is looking for

Comment: This is exacly what I need! Thanks.

Comment: No need for edits. I am working on existing page and will not be wrapping text with spans. Original solution did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use

```
.parentDiv > .column { font-weight: bold }
.parentDiv > .column > .fa { font-weight: normal }
```

Comment: This assumes that if a `.column` has a `.fa`, it won't have other contents without `.fa`.

Answer (score 0):

The way the [not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector works is that you have to target a specific element/class/ID. You would have to wrap the text from each column in a `span` and then add the `:not(.fa)` CSS to the `span`:

```css
.parentDiv > .column span:not(.fa) {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">

  <div class="column">
    <span>aaa</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span>bbb</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="fa">ccc</span>
  </div>

</div>
```